# How to solve "A" key working intermittently in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, laptop

The 'a' key on a [Lenovo IdeaPad 320-15IKB](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/320-15ikb?linkTrack=Homepage%3ABody_Search%20Products&searchType=3&keyWordSearch=320-15IKB%20(Type%2080XL%2C%2080YE)%20Laptop%20(ideapad)) laptop (80XL03FUIN) does not work as expected in 16.04. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't I don't apply any external pressure on my keyboard, but the 'a' key works when the 's' key adjacent to it is pressed. Here's the [link to the hardware manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad320-15isk_320x-15isk_320-15ikb_320x-15ikb_320-15ikbtouch_hmm_201704.pdf).

How may I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Carefully and gently examine under the "a" key to look for a foreign object. If found, remove with tweezers.

2) Does an external USB attached keyboard work OK? If so, it's your laptop keyboard.

3) Pages 31-32 of the  [hardware manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad320-15isk_320x-15isk_320-15ikb_320x-15ikb_320-15ikbtouch_hmm_201704.pdf) introduces you to working on a Lenovo laptop, and pages 65-70 lists all the different keyboard models available for all the different languages. Unless you are adept at electronics repair, the manual advises against repairing it yourself: "Do not attempt to replace an FRU on your own.... Only qualified technicians can inspect or repair this product."

Comment: yes it's my laptop issue :-( since the key 'a" works when the key adjacent to it 's' is pressed it starts working

Comment: apart from model no of laptop should I mention anything else?

Comment: Now it is happing with two keys together i.e with ('A') key and ('Fn' key) either both works or both don't . you still believe it to be hardware issue?

Comment: @Nimish Bansal If it doesn't happen with the external USB keyboard, I believe it is a hardware fault. I wish I knew the mechanics of that internal keyboard, for I have seen spills cause growing corruption on circuit boards.

Comment: I dont have externnal USB keyboards  :-(

Comment: @Nimish Bansal Strongly suggest you take your laptop to someplace which has one. Without testing with an external USB keyboard, you're wasting your time.

Comment: yes, I am in direct conversation with the warranty provider.